# Progress bar CONTROL

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть готовый прогресс бар . Кто знает как с горизонтального можно сделать вертикальный и + сделать рандомный ввод чисел с интервалом в 5 секунд . Помогите пожалуйста , вопрос жизни и смерти , мозг просто уже кипит (

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myButton').click(function () {
        animateProgressBar($('#ddlPercentage').val());
    });

    function animateProgressBar(percentageCompleted) {
        $('#innerDiv').animate({
            width: (500 * percentageCompleted) / 100
        }, 1000);

        $({ counter: 1 }).animate({ counter: percentageCompleted }, {
            duration: 1000,
            step: function () {
                $('#innerDiv').text(Math.ceil(this.counter) + '%');
            }
        })
    }
});
```

```html
        <html>
     <head>
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script>
 </head>
   <body style="font-family:Arial">
           Select Percentage :
          <select id="ddlPercentage">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="60">60</option>
        <option value="70">70</option>
        <option value="80">80</option>
        <option value="90">90</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Start Animation" />
    <br /><br />
    <div id="outerDiv" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;
         height:20px; width:500px; padding:5px">
        <div id="innerDiv" style="background-color:red; height:19px;
             width:0px; color:white; text-align:center">
        </div>
        </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    const fullRange = $('#outerDiv').height();
    $('#myButton').click(function () {
        animateProgressBar($('#ddlPercentage').val());
    });

    function animateProgressBar(percentageCompleted) {
        $('#innerDiv').animate({
            height: fullRange * percentageCompleted / 100,
            marginTop: fullRange * ( 1 - percentageCompleted / 100) 
        }, 1000);

        $({ counter: 1 }).animate({ counter: percentageCompleted }, {
            duration: 1000,
            step: function () {
                $('#innerDiv').text(Math.ceil(this.counter) + '%');
            }
        })
    }
    setInterval(() => animateProgressBar(Math.floor(Math.random()*100)), 5000)

});
```

```html
        <html>
     <head>
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script>
 </head>
   <body style="font-family:Arial">
           Select Percentage :
          <select id="ddlPercentage">
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="60">60</option>
        <option value="70">70</option>
        <option value="80">80</option>
        <option value="90">90</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="Start Animation" />
    <br /><br />
    <div id="outerDiv" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;
         width:20px; height: 500px; padding:5px">
        <div id="innerDiv" style="background-color:red; width:19px; height:0px; color:white; text-align:center; margin-top: 500px;">
        </div>
        </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Вот у меня тоже так получалось , сверху вниз показывало . А надо по принципу  "заполнения контейнера" снизу вверх

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex Обновил ответ. теперь снизу вверх

Comment: Спасибо огромное , самое оно)